# Anova table from regression

Tags: r, regression, anova

I would like to ask how to better understand anova output table once linear model is inserted.
Here I have prepared an example I would like to ask about:

```
library(tidyverse)

model1 <- lm(hp ~ wt + qsec + disp, data = mtcars)
model2 <- lm(hp ~ qsec + disp, data = mtcars)
summary(model1)

Y_mean <- mean(mtcars$hp)

summary(aov(model1))

model_help <- lm(hp ~ wt, data = mtcars)
sum((fitted(model_help) - Y_mean)^2)

model_help2 <- lm(hp ~ wt + qsec, data = mtcars)
sum((fitted(model_help2) - Y_mean)^2) - sum((fitted(model_help) - Y_mean)^2)
```

using command `summary(aov(model1))` we get a table where each "Sum sq" columns is regression sum of squared value once another regressor is added to the regression.

I would like to ask what NULL hypothesis is tested using F-test in the very same table?

Usually F-test is used to test for joint significance - either overall model or multiple regressors e.g.:

```
model_anova1 <- lm(hp ~ wt + qsec + disp, data = mtcars)
model_anova2 <- lm(hp ~ wt, data = mtcars)

anova(model_anova1, model_anova2)
```

Here the null tested is given as: [image]

Answer (score 0):

What is being compared here is the overall model fits (the residual sums of squares) of the two nested models. That is, is the overall fit of the more complex model (`hp ~ wt + qsec + disp`) no better than the overall fit of the less complexm model (`hp ~ wt`).

So, *RSS*<sub>bigModel</sub> − *RSS*<sub>smallModel</sub> = 0.

The default statistical test computed is against an *F* distribution. You can choose a different statistic using the `test` argument set to one of: `"Rao", "LRT", "Chisq", "F", "Cp"`. The likelihood ratio test (`"LRT"`) is probably preferred in most cases.

For more general discussion on model comparison methods, see [Model Selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_selection).